# Navmesh Agent rotate with mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation, agent

I would like to rotate my NavigationMeshAgent with reference to the mouse position. Following is my code to do so.

```
public class Navcontroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    private NavMeshAgent _agent;
    void Start()
    {
        _agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        float horInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(horInput, 0f, verInput);
        Vector3 moveDestination = transform.position + movement;
        _agent.destination = moveDestination;

    }
}
```

Unforutnately , the rotation is weird and it can look all over the place as I move the mouse. what am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

I have updated my code with the mouse position as follows,

```
public class Navcontroller : MonoBehaviour

{

// Start is called before the first frame update

private NavMeshAgent _agent;
float mouseX, mouseY;
float rotationSpeed = 1;

void Start()
{
    _agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    
    Cursor.visible = false;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    

    float horInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float verInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(horInput, 0f, verInput);
    Vector3 moveDestination = transform.position + movement ;
    
    mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed;
    mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeed;
    
    _agent.destination = moveDestination;

    _agent.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, 0);

}
```

}

Now that the agent rotates with the camera. But the agent is not moving in the same direction where he is looking at.

Comment: Do you want to rotate it around based on ray-cast or based on the 2d plane of your monitor, because right now you are doing the second one?

Comment: I would like to rotate the agent with based on the cursor position and travel in that direction when I press `wsad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment

```
Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition; // Get mouse position
mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition); //Transfom it to game space - form screen space
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(
mousePosition.x - transform.position.x,
mousePosition.y - transform.position.y
); // create new direction

transform.up = direction; // Rotate Z axis
```

Because based on the comment this has nothing to do with NavigationMeshAgent or AI. Then to move forward you do

```
if(Input.GetKey(Key.W)){
    transform.forward += Speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

**EDIT**

Your `_agent.destination = moveDestination;` needs to match your rotation so you need to multiply it by the rotation. `_agent.destination = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, 0) * moveDestination` where `moveDestination` should be relative to its rotation (not absolute as you probably have now) so better use `_agent.destination = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, 0) * Vector3.forward`

Comment: The agent did not turn around as I move the cursor :(

Comment: Your NavigationMeshAgent is overriding rotation, you need to get rid of it (because you are not using it) or call `agent.isStopped = true;` when you want to use WSAD as a controller

Comment: now that it rotates with the mouse but moves automatically. I want it to move only when I press the wsad :(